# Go Git - Recurse Submodules

Tags: go, go-git

I have a project which contains submodules as shown here.

```
[submodule "repo-a"]
    path = repo-a
    url = https://example.com/scm/repo-a.git
[submodule "repo-b"]
    path = repo-b
    url = https://example.com/scm/repo-b.git
[submodule "repo-c"]
    path = repo-c
    url = https://example.com/scm/repo-c.git
```

I am using go-git pkg and trying to clone with options as shown here,

```
cloneOpts := &git.CloneOptions{
      URL:               url,
      RecurseSubmodules: git.DefaultSubmoduleRecursionDepth,
}
```

It does not recursively pull the submodules. I see only empty directories. Am I missing something?

Comment: The go-git implementation doesn't use Git, so this is a pure go-git question.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, the `PlainClone` method correctly clones the submodules of a repo that I tested it with.

Comment: Yes, this needs a [mcve].

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi My parent module contains nothing but `.gitmodule` which is the above file. Do you have anything else?

Comment: @torek So what happens when you clone this [example repo](https://github.com/githubtraining/example-dependency)? Is the content of the `js` folder present? Otherwise I would need to see the code to help you better.

Comment: @OliverTale-Yazdi: using plain (not go-) Git, I get: `git submodule status` => `-c3c588713233609f5bbbb2d9e7f3fb4a660f3f72 js`. The current branch (as recommended by https://github.com/githubtraining/example-dependency) is `master` and its tip commit contains a gitlink named `js` pointing to that commit; the `.gitmodules` file has instructions for cloning the submodule. A subsequent `git submodule update --init` clones the submodule and does a detached-HEAD checkout of that commit, as one might expect. What does `go-git` do when one provides the remaining MRE? Where is that remaining MRE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even after your comments, I have no idea how you are currently using `go-git`; so please provide your source code.

I am now answering your original question of "how to clone a repo and its submodules" in `go-git`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "os"

    "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5"
)

func main() {
    repoURL := "https://github.com/githubtraining/example-dependency"
    clonePath := "example-repo"

    _, err := git.PlainClone(clonePath, false, &git.CloneOptions{
        URL:      repoURL,
        Progress: os.Stdout,
        // Enable submodule cloning.
        RecurseSubmodules: git.DefaultSubmoduleRecursionDepth,
    })

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    println("Have a look at example-repo/js to see a cloned sub-module")
}
```

As you can see after running this, `example-repo/js` contains the cloned submodule.

Comment: It works man. Sorry it was my fault. But i do appreciate you for taking time to create repo and show a working sample.

Comment: @RamPrakash No worries, I'm happy to help 